# Change cell value on button click to column value based on a criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I would like to change the value in cell G2 by clicking on a button (D3). The (A-column) values that are being looped through should meet the criteria "yes" in the column B.

[image: s]

Comment: An interesting question. What exactly is the problem that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's goal is to loop through the list of names stopping on each name with a value of "yes".

Obviously this requires skipping over the names with a value of "no". And there is a special challenge when dealing with the last name in the list AND that name having a "select" value of "no". In that case, the loop should "restart" at the top of the list.

The following code address each of these contingencies.

Using the sample data shown below; the code should stop on Paul, Dave, Brett and Ted.
 If the value in Cell G2 is "Ted", then the next selected name should be Paul.

---

**Sample data screenshot**
[image: Sample data screenshot]

---

```
function so5794149403() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('57941494');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vAnum = vA.length;

  var names = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  //flatten the array
  var users = names.map(function (row) { return row[0]; }); 

  // set some variables
  var i=0;
  var failedNTLN = 0; // fail but Not The Last Name
  var modifiedTLN = 0;// fail but The Last Name

  //Loop through names
  for (i;i<names.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG:0:i = "+i+" and failedNTLN = "+failedNTLN+" and modifiedTLN = "+modifiedTLN);

    if (failedNTLN ==99){
      // if last name was a failure AND it was not the Last name, then do nothing
    }
    else {

      // get the name in Cell G2
      var g2=sh.getRange("G2").getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:1 currently selected name = "+g2);

      // get the position of G2 in the list of names
      var Pos = users.indexOf(g2);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:1 position = "+Pos);

      if (modifiedTLN == 99){ 
        // if last name was a failure AND it was The Last Name
        i=0;
        Logger.log("DEBUG:1: modifiedTLN is "+modifiedTLN+", and i = "+i);
      }
      else{
        // test if this is the last name in the list
        if (Pos+1 == names.length){
          // this is the last name
          i=0;
          failedNTLN = 0;
          modifiedTLN = 0;
          Logger.log("DEBUG:1: Pos is last position. i = "+i)
        }
        else
        {
          // this is not the last name
          i = Pos+1;
          // Logger.log("DEBUG:1: Pos is NOT the last position. set i = "+i)
        }
      }
    }

    // Logger.log("DEBUG:1: settings are: i="+i+", next status = "+vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()+", next name = "+vA[i][0]+", g2 = "+g2);

    // logic statement if status = yes, and name isn't = G2
    if(vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()=='yes' && vA[i][0]!=g2) {

      // Logger.log("DEBUG:2: IF - outcome success: i="+i+", status = "+vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()+", name = "+vA[i][0]+" does not equal "+g2);
      sh.getRange("G2").setValue(vA[i][0]);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:2: setting G2 to "+vA[i][0]+", i = "+i+" and break") 
      failedNTLN=0;modifiedTLN=0;
      break;
    }
    else if (users.indexOf(vA[i][0]) == (names.length-1)){
      // the next name is the last name
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:3: the next name is the last name");
      modifiedTLN = 99;
      failedNTLN=0;
      i=0;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:3: position = "+users.indexOf(vA[i][0]))
      // Logger.log("DEBUG:3: the next name: "+users.indexOf(vA[i][0])+" is the last name;  i = "+i+"; set modifiedTLN to "+modifiedTLN+"; set failedNTLN to "+failedNTLN);
    }
    else{
      // the next name is NOT the last name
       failedNTLN = 99;
       modifiedTLN = 0;
       //Logger.log("DEBUG:4: the next name: "+users.indexOf(vA[i][0])+" is NOT the last name;  i = "+i+"; set failedNTLN to "+failedNTLN+"; set modifiedTLN to "+modifiedTLN);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @PDE To be honest, it is a cluge. It took a while to figure out that the code needed to test whether the "next name" AND the "current name" would fail the logic test. This introduced the challenge of managing the "last name" (`modifiedTLN`) AS WELL AS the "next to last name" (`failedNTLN`). A more experienced coder could, I believe, make this more elegant (and efficient?). But as they say, "Perfect is the enemy of good".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function makingChange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rg2=sh.getRange('G2');
  var vg2=rg2.getValue();
  var rgi=sh.getRange('H2');
  var vi=rgi.getValue();
  var sObj={nA:[]};
  var startIdx=!vi?0:vi;
  if(startIdx>=(vA.length-1))startIdx=0;
  for(var i=startIdx;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vg2 && vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()=='yes'){
      rg2.setValue(vA[i][0]);
      sh.getRange(i+2,1).activate();
      sh.getRange('H2').setValue(i);
      break
    }
    if(vg2 && vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()=='yes' && vA[i][0]!=vg2) {
      rg2.setValue(vA[i][0]);
      sh.getRange(i+2,1).activate();
      rgi.setValue(i);
      break;
    }
    if(vg2 && vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()=='no' && i==vA.length-1) {
      rg2.setValue('');
      rgi.setValue('');
      makingChange();//Thats right this runs the script over again
    }
  }
}
```

**Run this first**

It will give you a dialog with a button on it for running the above script.  Which will then cycle you through the lines with Yes in column 2.

```
function makeDialog() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="Run" onClick="google.script.run.makingChange();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
};
```

The Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: thanks Cooper, this loops great but the funny thing is that when I add rows to the range, these aren't added in the loop

Comment: It stops after the first yes in column two with a name that is not the one already in `G2`.  What did you want it to do?

Comment: Well names (and their selection label) will be added to the list. These added names shoudl be included in the loop. I presumed that `getLastRow` would make the range dynamic but it doesn't. TIA

Comment: In that case the change that dominates the final outcome will always  be the last one.  If that's what you want then remove the break statement.

Comment: Great, thanks for giving me a greater insight into Google apps script and your time!

Comment: @PDE The mod to address repeated names is a worthwhile feature, and not covered in my answer. But... in both our answers, if the last name is the same as the third last name AND both have value = "yes", AND the second last name is not the same as either of those two names AND has a value of no, then the code never advances beyond the third last name. The solution to this complex programming challenge is blindingly simple - "no repeated names". For example, change "Ted" to "Ted B1" and "Ted B2".  This ![image](https://i.imgur.com/IAAlsqz.jpg) shows what I mean.